# Caching entities using Spring-Integration framework and apache Camel

Tags: spring, caching, apache-camel, distributed-caching, spring-integration

I'm browsing Integration frameworks to choose the best one for my integration problem. one thing that I want to know is caching and distributed caching for example using Web Service for communications, supported or not ? and if it does, how ?

in [Pro Spring Integration](http://www.apress.com/9781430233459) CHAPTER 16 ■ SCALING YOUR SPRING INTEGRATION APPLICATION 
page 544, they talk about some caching strategy but they didn't say how to implement them using Spring-integration ?
also they talk about message caching somewhere I want to know is there a caching solution for entities between multiple machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Camel provides integration with existing caching technologies like EhCache, Hazelcast, Memcached (via Kestrel), etc.

http://camel.apache.org/cache.html

http://camel.apache.org/hazelcast-component.html

http://camel.apache.org/kestrel.html

Comment: thanks for your help. could you please provide me some links and tutorials of how to implement distributed caching using camel ?

Comment: I've used Hazelcast for this, don't know of any specific documentations other than hazelcast.com...but if you can deploy Camel to multiple machines, then camel-hazelcast makes it easy to do clustered caching between the servers, etc...